# Automatically look up arXiv reference information

Tags: bibliographies, arxiv

Does any editor or *TeX front-end provide the following feature?

Given an [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) preprint number, say `1234.5678`, automatically produce the relevant bibtex entry. This could be done for instance by looking up the webpage `http://arxiv.org/abs/1234.5678` whose source contains something like

```
<meta name="citation_title" content="Interesting facts about sequences of digits" />
<meta name="citation_author" content="A. Bethe" />
<meta name="citation_author" content="F. Gamov" />
<meta name="citation_date" content="2034/12/24" />
<meta name="citation_online_date" content="2034/12/25" />
```

I'm open to other bibliography tools than bibtex. And it does not need to be at the level of the editor. Of course, this could be done within the TeX run with shell escape, but letting TeX access the internet is a massive security risk `:)`.

Comment: Bruno try [Jabref](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/). You can also try your own with server side JavaScript.

Comment: I have a modified version of refbase which has the ability to directly import from the arxiv. It also mirrors the daily lists so I can just click on a link as I browse to import the reference.  Incidentally, the arxiv has an API which is better suited to scripting than the main pages.

Comment: Indeed, the arXiv preprint fetch tool of Jabref works quite OK.

Comment: This got me thinking about another problem. Does anyone know if you can search arXiv by DOI? I know that DOIs aren't arXiv IDs, but often authors supply an article with a DOI on publication. Sometimes the article name will differ, so the quickest way to check for an arXiv version would be by searching for a DOI...

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt you might have better luck asking that as a real question on one of the sister sites (dunno which one, though).

Comment: Wikipedia has a [comparison of reference management softwares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software) which can be relevant relative to that question.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Just throwing it out there. It'd be good to be able to gather arXiv IDs and DOIs at the same time for scrapers.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt maybe this somewhat related question is intersting for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/automatically-dereference-doi-to-bib

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I only know ((pdf)e)TeX coding :), so I'll have trouble writing something in JavaScript.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch It's not much different:) It just uses different syntax!

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt You can do a full text search on the arxiv so if all else fails, you could search for the DOI on that.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Looked at that a few hours back, and it was sloooooooooooooooooow. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've written a python script that returns the corresponding bib-entry from an arxiv ID, you can find it on http://www.thamnos.de/misc/look-up-bibliographical-information-from-an-arxiv-id/ . If you save it e.g. as arxiv2bib.py, you can call it as `arxiv2bib.py 1234.5678` or as `arxiv2bib.py http://arxiv.org/abs/1234.5678`.

Answer (score 6):

Jabref is indeed one of the solution. 
It is not a *Tex editor, it is a bibliography manager.

The conjonction Jabref / Biblatex is, IMHO, the best solution for dealing with bibliographies in LaTeX.

Jabref provides with web searches/fetches for arXiv (Maj + F8), but also for JSTOR, SPIRES, IEEEXplore, ACM portal, Medline, ScienceDirect and Citeseer.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/). It can download papers as well as look up der bibligraphic info from arxiv. What I like a lot is that it can also organize the pdfs. Also it is integrated in Word - in case you want to use the same bibliography for such a document.