# BibDesk: script to find ad add DOI

Tags: bibdesk

I've downloaded the "[Find DOI.applescript](https://github.com/ghoetker/BibDeskAppleScripts/tree/master/Find%20DOI)" to automatically find and add DOI into a BibDesk item.

The script requires an installation of JSON Helper for AppleScript and Satimage.osax. I've installated both on my iMac (OSX 12.7.2) but the script doesn't work.

Anyone could help?

Comment: The question is unclear at the moment. What are the exact steps to reproduce, including the steps to actually add a DOI to a specific entry? When you say it "doesn't work", what does that mean, do you get errors or warnings, or wrong output, or no output? However, while clarifying your questions is always good, in this case it seems that the script itself does no longer work in newer versions of macOS (see https://github.com/ghoetker/BibDeskAppleScripts/issues/1#issuecomment-435247874) so you probably need to find a different solution.

Comment: I use BibDesk. If I need a single DOI, I get it from [Crossref Search](https://search.crossref.org) on the web. I have never needed to batch add DOIs to many BibTeX records, but if I needed to do it, I would use [Zotero](https://zotero.org/) + [Better BibTeX for Zotero (BBT)](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex) + [DOI Manager for Zotero](https://github.com/bwiernik/zotero-shortdoi). Import BibTeX to Zotero using BBT, fetch all DOIs using DOI Manager, export to BibTeX again with BBT.

Comment: See also the answers in [Automatically adding DOI fields to a hand-made bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6810), especially [this answer that points to a Python package to autocomplete BibTeX entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637689/121590) that can be used to add DOIs from the command line, which is much more efficient than the alternative in my previous comment.